# hibernate collection - invalid column index

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have created a parent and child class in hibernate and JPA. When I attempt to persist the class I get a SQL exception stating "invalid column index".

This is the parent class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vnd_base_file_format")
public class VendorBaseFileFormat implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "base_file_format_id")
    private int baseFileFormatId;

    @Column(name = "vendor_id")
    private int vendorId;

    @Column(name = "format_name")
    private String formatName;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;

    @Column(name = "month_year_format")
    private String monthYearFormat;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="base_file_format_id", nullable=false)
    @OrderBy("index")
    private List<VendorBaseFileDimension> dimensions;
```

This is the child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vnd_base_file_format_dim")
public class VendorBaseFileDimension implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "dimension_id")
    private int dimensionId;

    @Column(name = "alternate_name")
    private String alternateName;

    @Column(name = "dimension_index")
    private int index;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="base_file_format_id", nullable=false, insertable=false)
    private VendorBaseFileFormat format;
```

I simply create the parent class and add one child class to it.  When I call entityManager.persist I get the following message:

```
Hibernate: insert into vnd_base_file_format (enabled, format_name, month_year_format, vendor_id, base_file_format_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vnd_base_file_format_dim (alternate_name, dimension_index, base_file_format_id, dimension_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
[21:53:01.159] WARN  JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 17003, SQLState: 99999
[21:53:01.159] ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter - Invalid column index
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I have tried a few things like setting insertable to false, but no luck.  I did see one question out there that mentioned there might be a problem with composite keys.  Do I really have to create a unique sequence column on the child when it is only going to exist as part of the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another question with a solution that was helpful. I changed the individual id columns into a composite key object and this seemed to work for me.

The main information that I needed was found in this article [here.](http://beavercreekconsulting.com/blog/2008/10/hibernate-annotations-for-a-one-to-many-mapping/)

The question that helped me figure it out was posted [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946416/mapping-issue-with-multi-field-primary-keys-using-hibernate-jpa-annotations)

Answer (score 0):

I can see your orderBy annotation is having name of the field as "index". You should provide one getter for index from your other class or try changing it to "dimension_index". Hopefully it should resolve the issue.

Comment: I changed the field name `index` to `dimensionIndex`, but I still received the same error

Comment: And I believe you have the getter already for the column correct?

Comment: Yes. I have getters and setters for all the columns and I renamed the `index` ones to `dimensionIndex` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem with index column occurs because you use List collection for holding relationship. You can do such things:

1) Change List to Set in VendorBaseFileFormat class;

2) Add *@IndexColumn(name="idx")* annotation to your class and explicitly specify by this column that will be used for holding list index. You should also add this column to *vnd_base_file_format_dim* table. In this [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/) exists example of bidirectional one-to-many mapping using List (section 8).

Comment: I tried using _@IndexColumn_ instead of _@OrderBy_, but I get the same error